# NgFor isn't displaying the array ii give him

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm developing an app for people working in restaurants, I have a dashboard where i show them some stats about their reservations, in which there is a part showing the 5 clients with the most reservations in a given period.

I send an array of 5 clients to my *ngFor but none of them is displaying.

A part of my typescript :

```
    for (let i = 0; i < topClient.length; i++) {
      this.clientService.retrieve(topClient[i]).subscribe(res => {
        this.topUsers.push(res.body);
      });
    }
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="flex flex w-full" *ngFor="let client of topUsers">
      <p class="w-64">{{ client.last_name }} {{ client.first_name }}</p>
</div>
```

I expect the output to be a list of my 5 clients, knowing that console.log(this.topUsers) is returning the expected 5 clients.

Thanks for help :')

EDIT : Here are the console.log of TopUsers and the console Error following Tony's changes :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04W7r.png)

Comment: Hey ! What does `topClient` is ? I think it would be easier if you had a method `getClients()` in your service. This method should return an Observable of Client type. Then, in your component, you just had to make something like that : `this.clients$ = this.clientService.getClients()`

Comment: Do you maybe have an element in your template which has #topUsers?

Comment: @Flacype checkout this example [http-call in for loop](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-promise-observable-http-request-for-loop-in-angular)

Comment: Could you show us a console.log of `res.body`, i.e a single object?

Comment: Only an advertistment. If you need a loop of Observables, use forkJoin

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your data like this to see if it work

```
this.topUsers = res.body;
```

And in your template

```
<div class="flex flex w-full" *ngFor="let client of topUsers">
      <p class="w-64">{{ client.last_name }} {{ client.first_name }}</p>
</div>
```

If it not the case check you are import `CommonModule` in your app.module.ts or not

Comment: That didn't work, i got a console error saying that ngFor can only binds to Arrays, my console.log(TopUsers) looks like a normal array ( (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] ) so  i guess it's not because of it ? And i use an ngFor somewhere else in another component and it's working perfectly fine :/

Comment: Can you take a screen shot a update in your question ?

Comment: can you try {{topUsers | json}} and share with us the result

Comment: {{topUsers | json}} returns a full working json of every clientObject and every object related to it by a ForeignKey, it's sadly way too long for me to copy paste it here :/

Comment: @TonyNgo, with your update i got the same error as the first version of your answer, it can't iterate over an object and needs an Array

Comment: Then your return data is not an array. Try to fix the API the problem is come from that

Comment: If i change this.topUsers = res.body; to this.topUsers = [res.body], i actually got an array, but it again does not display in my ngFor

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to an array.

```
this.topUsers = [res.body]
```

Also, check your module whether you have imported '**CommonModule**'.